# html Input field is auto filled with username saved in browser form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Problem:
I created an input field with type text, but when page loads it is auto filled with username saved (saved for this website login page)in browsers form data. i want to show it clean when page load.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Search Item" 
ng-model="vm.applyCategFoodSearch" autocomplete="off" 
name="txtFieldForSearchItems">
```

i am unable to find solution, autocomplete='off' was suggested by many other sources, but issue not fixed. if it can be handled using html,jquery,javascript,angularjs. it will be good.
I also reset the values in controller

```
 vm.applyCategFoodSearch='';
```

timeout also tried but not working

```
      $timeout( function(){
         vm.applyCategFoodSearch='';
    }, 5000 );
```

if i set time out to 10seconds, it will work, but its not the solution. i am sending ajax call for food categories,when it returns, this timeout code will run with 10second delay.it will work. other than 10second delay.it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you may set it to empty string.

```
applyCategFoodSearch="";
```

basically it will be like this `$scope.applyCategFoodSearch=""` or `this.applyCategFoodSearch=""` , depends on whichever you prefer

Comment: I done this as well, but still not working. i also do this by setting timeout,it is not working.

Comment: share the complete code

Comment: ok i edit the question,

Answer (score 1):

`autocomplete='off'` these days is ignore by major browsers. I suggest that you create a random string for each session and when you are outputting html you append the random String to name parameter value. For example , suppose the random String is "fjsdorf" , you can output this `name="fjsdorf_txtFieldForSearchItems"`. When you get the data at the server , you can  append the random String when you want to access the parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

try this, hope this helps:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

or try with jquery on page load:

```
$('input#Password').val('');
```

Comment: i do this, but its not working,